Yara with androguard module
I'm trying to run some yara rules using the androguard module.
I manually compiled the yara-python, I installed the androguard module, but I keep having error with the module:
yara.compile(filepaths={"yara":"Desktop/yara.yara"}, includes=True)
--------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
yara.SyntaxError: Desktop/yara.yara(100): invalid field name "package_name"

